# How can I improve this program design for a simple todo list manager?

Tags: c, algorithm

For a simple command-line todo manager (that is to be implemented in C), this is what I have thought of the design:

- The utility would support multiple users by storing the todo's in different files for each
- While running the program would hold all the data in memory itself. This would avoid unnecessary IO and is also quite suitable when you do not expect the user to have more than 20 todos (I am assuming this is true). So, if the user already exists, the user todo file would be read and all the data captured to memory (in arrays of rows(structures)) and then when user logs out the file would be updated.

The aim of the project is to show how it can be done while keeping things very simple.

This pseudo pseudocode outlines the structure

```
// define data structure memory limits
// and other constants

bootup() {
    // initialize data structures
}

readfile() {
    use rot13();
}

writefile() {
    use rot13();
}

login() {
    ask_for_username
    search for file or create one
    if file present
        readfile();
    ... and populate data structures
}

//1.
enter_new_task() {
    read
    record_time
    is_starred
    optional_due_date
}

//2.
...

fetch_commands() {
    show_command_menu();
    // 1. enter a new task
    // 2. see the list of tasks
    // 3. delete a task
    // 4. edit a task
    // 5. sort tasks by
}

while_not_logout() {
    display_ui();
    fetch_command();
    while(command != logout) {
        execute_command();
        update_ui();
        fetch_command();
    }
    writefile();
}

cleanup() {
    // free memory
}

int main() {
    bootup();
    login();
    while_not_logout();
    cleanup();
}
```

**How can I improve the program structure/execution flow?**

I want to know where all can I improve the program structure before I start plugging in the actual code. Any suggestions/comments are welcome.

Comment: Personally i think the requirements are quite..unclear. Do you have to support concurrent access? What happens, if you read a file, the user manipulates, and you app crashes? Data will be lost...

Comment: As I mentioned, things have to be kept very simple - no concurrent access, no advanced crash handling, I have even used rot13 in the name of encryption!

Comment: So, i think your structure is simple and does not need to be improved so far. I guess its the "normal" way as a lot ppl would do. Login/Read/Menu/Write/Logout

Comment: @ Lazer: Why would you store data in files? Isn't SQLite a better option?

Comment: @Andrew: yes, it would be a good option, however too much for this simple prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep everything in memory, then only call `writefile` from `cleanup`, or from `main` after `while_not_logout`. Why not support multiple users by keeping their todo list in their own homedir?

Comment: multiuser support is very much there, each user creates his own uniquely named todo list file in `{ask_for_username, search for file or create one}` part.